Issue with Pagination in Youtube Shorts Using YouTube API v3
I'm trying to retrieve video details from YouTube Shorts using YouTube API v3. My goal is to create a dataframe where each row corresponds to a Shorts video uploaded by a specific channel, with columns identifying the video details.
Problem:
YouTube seems to cap the number of extracted videos at 3000 for a channel, even though my quota limit hasn't been reached. This makes me suspect an internal cap on the number of videos extractable from a single channel.
When trying to continue fetching videos from the last stored page token, it only returns the same 50 results from the last token, rather than retrieving older videos.
Context:
Since the YouTube API v3 doesn't specifically handle Shorts, I learned from a StackOverflow thread that Shorts can be treated as a playlist. Using the channel ID, I can recreate a "playlist ID" to identify all Shorts videos uploaded by that channel.
Steps Taken:
I run the initial extraction using the get_playlist_videos_and_store_last_token function.
I store the last valid token and plan to continue extraction the next day using the continue_from_last_token function.
However, after running the second function, it doesn't seem to retrieve any older videos.
Questions:

Is there a limit to how many videos can be extracted from a single playlist or channel in YouTube API v3?
Could there be an issue with how I'm handling pagination and tokens in the second function?
Any suggestions for how to bypass this cap or retrieve the remaining videos?

Below is the code I'm using for this task in Python. I use Google Colab to run it.
# YouTube API setup
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=API_KEY)

# Function to fetch detailed information for a list of video IDs
def get_video_details(video_ids):
    videos = []
    for i in range(0, len(video_ids), 50):
        request = youtube.videos().list(
            part='snippet,statistics,contentDetails',
            id=','.join(video_ids[i:i+50])
        )
        response = request.execute()
        for item in response['items']:
            video_info = {
                'video_id': item['id'],
                'title': item['snippet']['title'],
                'description': item['snippet']['description'],
                'published_at': item['snippet']['publishedAt'],
                'tags': item['snippet'].get('tags', 'No tags'),
                'viewCount': item['statistics'].get('viewCount', 'No data'),
                'duration': item['contentDetails'].get('duration', 'No data')
            }
            videos.append(video_info)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    return videos

# Function to convert channel ID to Shorts playlist ID
def get_shorts_playlist_id(channel_id):
    if channel_id.startswith("UC"):
        return channel_id.replace('UC', 'UUSH', 1)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid channel ID format. It should start with 'UC'.")

# Function to fetch videos from a playlist
def get_playlist_videos_and_store_last_token(playlist_id, max_results=50):
    videos = []
    video_ids = []
    next_page_token = ""
    last_valid_token = None
    while True:
        response = youtube.playlistItems().list(
            part='snippet',
            playlistId=playlist_id,
            maxResults=max_results,
            pageToken=next_page_token
        ).execute()
        for item in response.get('items', []):
            video_ids.append(item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])
        next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')
        if not next_page_token:
            break
        time.sleep(0.5)
    if video_ids:
        videos = get_video_details(video_ids)
    return pd.DataFrame(videos)

# Function to continue fetching videos using the last token
def continue_from_last_token(playlist_id, max_results=50):
    try:
        with open("last_page_token.txt", "r") as file:
            start_token = file.read().strip()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        start_token = ""
    videos = []
    video_ids = []
    next_page_token = start_token
    while True:
        response = youtube.playlistItems().list(
            part='snippet',
            playlistId=playlist_id,
            maxResults=max_results,
            pageToken=next_page_token
        ).execute()
        for item in response.get('items', []):
            video_ids.append(item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])
        next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')
        if not next_page_token:
            break
        time.sleep(0.5)
    if video_ids:
        videos = get_video_details(video_ids)
    return pd.DataFrame(videos)


What channel id have you tried with?

Hi @BenjaminLoison. I tried with this channel ID "UCZFMm1mMw0F81Z37aaEzTUA". Weirdly, it just always returns ~3000 results from now to the earliest point (normally around July). Then, even using the last token returned as input to my pageToken (in this case, "EAAaf1BUOkNMZ1hJaEF4TkRGQ09UUTBSalEyTXpjeVJESXlLQUZJdGR1SC05eVlpZ05RQVZvNUlrTm9jRlpXVms1SlYydGFUbUpVUm5SVVdHTjNVbXBuZUZkcVRUTlpWMFpHWld4U1ZsRlNTVXhEUzIweU1UZHZSMFZKYW1sM1J6Z2k"), it does not extract further 3000 results before that. It stops at this token forever, even if I'm still way below my api quota limit.

To clarify, Youtube seems to return page tokens only until this certain threshold, even if there are more videos from this playlist.
Using API explorer, for example, I tried a simple thing -- inputting the last page token EAAaf1BUOkNMZ1hJaEF4TkRGQ09UUTBSalEyTXpjeVJESXlLQUZJdGR1SC05eVlpZ05RQVZvNUlrTm9jRlpXVms1SlYydGFUbUpVUm5SVVdHTjNVbXBuZUZkcVRUTlpWMFpHWld4U1ZsRlNTVXhEUzIweU1UZHZSMFZKYW1sM1J6Z2k
And in the results, it hasn't returned me any nextPageToken string, only a prevPageToken string as if I had reached a boundary.

Someone has raised the exact same issue in another forum, and apparently this is an old issue that's never been solved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35178193
